# Woocommerce - Change quick view button text and Eye icon

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Im working with Wordpress.

For the last hour Im trying to find a code in php. files considering the "Quick view" button, but with no results.

Does anyone know where I can find it?

Best regards.

Filip

Comment: It seems a custom button which is created by a custom theme, There isn't a Quick view button in woocommerce as far as I know. :D, 
more details would be helpful

Comment: have you tried using this filter `woocommerce_loop_quick_view_button` ?

Comment: no Shashin. May explain how to? Im not an php. expert :)
Still learning everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [this plugin](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-quick-view/) for the quick view

You can try this code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_quick_view_button','custom_quick_view');
function custom_quick_view($output)
{
 $output = 'My Cutom Output';
  return $output;
}
```

For OceanWP theme please try this code:

```
add_filter('ocean_woo_quick_view_button_html','custom_quick_view');
function custom_quick_view($output)
{
 global $product;

 $output  = '<a href="#" id="product_id_' . $product->get_id() . '" 
       class="owp-quick-view" data-product_id="' . $product->get_id() . '"><i 
       class="icon-eye"></i>' . esc_html__( 'Quick View', 'oceanwp' ) . '</a>';  //Edit the $output as you want
 return $output;
}
```

Place this code in your **functions.php**

Comment: Im not using any plugin. I think that it is from OceanWP theme, because class in html is "owp-quick-view". But I cant find any of it in OceanWP php. files

Comment: Plese add `;` at the end of the first line i've updated my answer. Sorry :)

Comment: Could you replace the first line with this one:  `add_filter('ocean_woo_quick_view_button_html','custom_quick_view');`

Comment: the content is changed! But the button itself is all messed up now. Its not a button anymore with its properties, and its positioned wierdly.

Comment: You should take care of that yourself :) try to get the original button content and edit it as required.

Comment: I tried to copy CSS but didnt work. Did class get another name?

Comment: its working!! Thanks alot man. I wish I could grab you a beer :)) .
Wish I understood the code ;(.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the eCommerce plugin you are using and also on the theme. If you are using woocommerce with a theme built for woocommerce then you can find these kind of things in "woocomerce" folder located in theme directory. If there is no such directory in your theme then take a look at woocommerce plugin directory.

Comment: I use OceanWP theme.

Comment: <a href="#" id="product_id_585" class="owp-quick-view" data-product_id="585"><i class="icon-eye"></i>Quick View</a>

this is in html

Comment: For OceanWP theme kindly check the "woocommerce" folder available in theme directory. You would see "quick-view.php" file there!

Comment: I did. But I can only see php/html commands. I dont see a line of code where I could change the content of quick view.

Comment: What you actually want to change there? Because you won't be able to see that line of code like that in theme files because of WP dynamic features.

Comment: You can also find some relevant code here in "oceanwp\inc\customizer\settings\woocommerce.php"

Comment: I want to translate "Quick view" text into my language, same as "Out of stock".

Comment: Oh okay then open that file "oceanwp\inc\customizer\settings\woocommerce.php"
search "Heading Quick View" and try to replace text 'Quick View' from following line to whatever you want "esc_html__( 'Quick View', 'oceanwp' ),"

Comment: I changed it. But now how do I apply it to my child theme? In my OceanWP child theme folder there are no directories like that.

Comment: Are you using a free version of OceanWP? If yes then you will find the same directory there as well. Also to make edits in child theme you need to replicate the directory structure with "woocommerce.php" file to your child theme folder and need to make edits there.

Comment: Not working. I copied entire Inc directory to my child theme and nothing.

I also added that woocommerce php. file into my child theme directory, and found it in my CMS with all the changes, updated, and nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok If anyone looking to change the text this how I did it and it works with any Theme:

Just add this a snippet in WordPress so you don't need to play around with function file or even when you update the theme or the plugin it will not change or break the text.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_quick_view_button','custom_quick_view');
function custom_quick_view($output)
{
 global $product;

 $output  = '<a href="#" id="product_id_' . $product->get_id() . '" 
       class="quick-view-button button" data-product_id="' . $product->get_id() . '"><i 
       class="icon-eye"></i>' . esc_html__( 'Buy Now', 'wc_quick_view' ) . '</a>';  //Edit the $output as you want
 return $output;
}
```